# Custom Spinner Pop Up

Tags: android, popup, spinner

I would like to modify the spinner pop up dialog . I would like to implement my own custom spinner pop up.

Is it possible or not ? Can anyone provide me solution to implement custom spinner pop up ?

This is an effort of uniformity for my various pop ups in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this here is the simple example which gives you the idea how to build custom spinner...

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html